# Trying to inherit Timepicker component from ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, inheritance, components

I am trying to extend Bootstraps TimePicker. So far I am having problem as model seams to be undefined. Will explain better with code.
This is the Git link to the TimePicker:
https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/timepicker/timepicker.ts

What I tried is to extend the NgbTimepicker and change some methods to fit my use case like this.

```
export class MyTimepickerComponent extends NgbTimepicker {

  constructor(_config: NgbTimepickerConfig, _ngbTimeAdapter: NgbTimeAdapter<any>, _cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(_config, _ngbTimeAdapter, _cd);
    console.log('_config', _config);
  }

  changeHour(step: number) {
    debugger;
    this.model.changeHour(step);
    this.propagateModelChange();
  }

}
```

Unfortunately this.model is always undefined. I have copied .html and .scss classes also.

Comment: Can you create a quick stackblitz?

Comment: Sure here you go, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xto1z4

Comment: I added the `changeHour` function from your code and it is working fine, and this.model is defined and giving correct value. Am I missing something?

Comment: @yazantahhan Sorry I continued working in that stackblitz and was able to fix it. Thanks to helping.